# PHP Array printing in a different format

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having troubles printing my array in the following format:

```
"key, value"
```

My current array as the following format:

```
array(51) {
    ["t"]=>
        int(3)
    ["I"]=>
        int(3)
    ["co"]=>
        int(3)
    ["http"]=>
        int(3)
    ["it"]=>
        int(2)
    ["new"]=>
        int(1)
    ["project"]=>
        int(1)
}
```

Any idea on can I format the array so it shows like I need?

Comment: `foreach($myCurrentArray as $key => $value) { echo '"', $key, ',', $value, '"<br />'; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo '"'.$key.', '.$value.'"';
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Where `$array` is your initial array.